# перемещение элемента с помощью AngularJS или JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

Задача такая есть: несколько кнопок, если нажать одну из них то к ней должен переместиться элемент, в данном случае просто текст. 
Я реализовал следующим образом, но понимаю что это слишком варварский способ.

HTML

```
 <div>
     <button ng-click="Foo_First($event)">button1</button>
     <button ng-click="Foo_First($event)">button2</button>
     <button ng-click="Foo_First($event)">button3</button>
 </div
<div class="object"  ng-style="{position: 'absolute', 'left': newPos + 'px', color: color}">
    {{newPos + 'px'}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
Myapp.controller("FirstCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.newPos = 0;

    $scope.Foo_First = function ($event) {
        console.log('lef:', angular.element($event.target).css('height'));
        $scope.newPos=angular.element($event.target).prop('offsetLeft');
    }
});
```

Comment: Чем вам не нравиться ваш способ?

Comment: Мне кажется что ng-style это не самый хороший тон.

Comment: @LevR поскольку ваш стиль динамичен, не вижу ничего смертельного в использовании `ng-style`